# How to get Tags with specific post id

Tags: posts, custom-taxonomy, wp-query, tags

I have created one post and post ID is 34 and added some Tags and Now I want to retrieve all tags with post ID.

[image]

Any Idea?

Answer (score 3):

Put this inside your loop:

```
//Returns All Term Items for "my_term"
$term_list = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'post_tag', array("fields" => "all"));
print_r($term_list);
```

Slightly adapted from [`wp_get_post_terms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms#Examples)

Comment: Thanks for response but I am getting this `WP_Error Object ( [errors] => Array ( [invalid_taxonomy] => Array ( [0] => Invalid taxonomy ) ) [error_data] => Array ( ) )`

Comment: Any Idea about this?

Comment: Where do you call this?

Comment: In single.php file.

Comment: You are using standard tags, not some custom taxonomy, right? I just tested the code and it works here. Check if you copied everything as I wrote it.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can retrieve tags

```
$tax_tags = get_terms(array('post_tag'));
   foreach($tax_tags as $tag){
     ?>
       <p>
     <?php echo ucfirst($tag->taxonomy).' : ' ?>
         <a href="<?php echo get_term_link($tag); ?>"><?php echo $tag->name ?></a>
       </p>
     <?php
}
```

Customize it the way you like.

`get_terms(array('post-tag'));` fetches you tag related to a post.

You can put this code within or outsode the default loop.

Reference: [get_terms](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms)